# historybp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: django, function, url, mapping

HTML

```
"<td><h4><a href="/cyphys/{{user_name}}/historybp/{{current_patient_obj.patientID}}/">BP</a></h4></td>"
```

here is `views.py`

```
@login_required
def historybp(request, patientID):
    context = { 'pid':patientID}
    return HttpResponse("request for bp history received")
```

and here is `urls.py`

```
    url(r'^(?P<name>\w+)/historybp/(?P<patientID>\d+)/$', historybp),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `name` in your url regex, so you need to pass this argument to your view too.